# Regex match all words enclosed by parentheses and separated by a pipe

Tags: c#, regex

I think an image a better than words sometimes.

[image]

My problem as you can see, is that It only matches two words by two. How can I match all of the words ?

My current regex (PCRE) : `([^\|\(\)\|]+)\|([^\|\(\)\|]+)`

The goal : retrieve all the words in a separate groupe for each of them

Comment: So it's supposed to match `fish`? that is the problem?

Comment: Sorry for not being clear enough. It is supposed to match all of the words until the end of the prenthese.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use an infinite length lookbehind in C# (with a lookahead):

```cs
(?<=\([^()]*)\w+(?=[^()]*\))
```

To match any kind of strings inside parentheses, that do not consist of `(`, `)` and `|`, you will need to replace `\w+` with `[^()|]+`:

```cs
(?<=\([^()]*)[^()|]+(?=[^()]*\))
//            ^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%29%5Cw%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%29&i=I%20love%20%28chocolate%7Cfish%7Choney%7Cmore%29) (and [regex demo #2](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5C%28%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%29%5B%5E%28%29%7C%5D%2B%28%3F%3D%5B%5E%28%29%5D*%5C%29%29&i=I%20love%20%28chocolate%7Csea%20fish%7Choney%7Cmore-text%C2%A7!%40%23%24%25%5E%20..%20with%20symbols%29%20and%20%28some%7Cmore%20stuff%E2%80%94%E2%80%93%7B%7D%29)). *Details*:

- `(?<=\([^()]*)` - a positive lookbehind that matches a location that is immediately preceded with `(` and then zero or more chars other than `(` and `)`
- `\w+` - one or more word chars
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` and then a `)` char.

Another way to *capture* these words is by using

```cs
(?:\G(?!^)\||\()(\w+)(?=[^()]*\))     // words as units consisting of letters/digits/diacritics/connector punctuation
(?:\G(?!^)\||\()([^()|]+)(?=[^()]*\)) // "words" that consist of any chars other than (, ) and |
```

See [this regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3f%3a%5cG%28%3f!%5e%29%5c%7c%7c%5c%28%29%28%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3d%5b%5e%28%29%5d*%5c%29%29&i=I+love+%28chocolate%7cfish%7choney%7cmore%29). The words you need are now in Group 1. *Details*:

- `(?:\G(?!^)\||\()` - a position after the previous match (`\G(?!^)`) and a `|` char (`\|`), or (`|`) a `(` char (`\(`)
- `(\w+)` - Group 1: one or  more word chars
- `(?=[^()]*\))` - a positive lookahead that makes sure there is a `)` char after any zero or more chars other than `(` and `)` to the right of the current position.

Extracting the matches in C# can be done with

```cs
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?<=\([^()]*)\w+(?=[^()]*\))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Value);

// Or
var matches = Regex.Matches(text, @"(?:\G(?!^)\||\()(\w+)(?=[^()]*\))")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .Select(x => x.Groups[1].Value);
```

Comment: This is cool because it will match words even with other separators. However wouldn't `(?<=[(|])\w+(?=[|)])` be simpler and better fit OP's need?

Comment: I couldn't expect better. Excellent ! Thank you very much this is exactly what I was looking for 

Comment: @Keytrap You are welcome. Also, here is a [C# demo](https://ideone.com/npf4wF).

Comment: Sorry just realised a slight error (I didn't mention this sorry), could it match words even with a space in them ? For example (first|second|third and fourth) would be `first` `second` `third and fourth` ?

Comment: @Keytrap Replace `\w+` with `[^()|]+`.

Answer (score 1):

In c# you can also make use of the group captures using a capture group.

The matches are in named group `word`

```
\((?<word>\w+)(?:\|(?<word>\w+))*\)
```

- `\(` Match `(`
- `(?<word>\w+)` Match 1+ word chars in group `word`
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `\|` Match `|`
  - `(?<word>\w+)` Match 1+ word chars
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat to get all occurrences
- `\)` Match the closing parenthesis

Code example provided by Wiktor Stribiżew in the comments:

```
var line = "I love (chocolate|fish|honey|more)";
var output = Regex.Matches(line, @"\((?<word>\w+)(?:\|(?<word>\w+))*\)")
    .Cast<Match>()
    .SelectMany(x => x.Groups["word"].Captures);
foreach (var s in output)
        Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Output

```
chocolate
fish
honey
more
```

foreach (var s in output)
Console.WriteLine(s);

[Regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5c%28%28%3f%3cword%3e%5cw%2b%29%28%3f%3a%5c%7c%28%3f%3cword%3e%5cw%2b%29%29*%5c%29&i=I+love+%28chocolate%7cfish%7choney%7cmore%29)

[image]

Comment: Unfortunately this matches when words a separated by a pipe and when all of them are enclosed by parentheses but it does't separate each word in a group. The answer from @Wiktor was the right. Thank you for your time anyways :)

Comment: @Keytrap You just need to get the `CaptureCollection` (`match.Groups["word"].Captures`) where each captured value is located. See [the C# demo](https://ideone.com/qNIfWP). This is also a valid solution that can be used in C#.

Comment: @Thefourthbird You can probably create a better demo, I do not think the one  I "cooked" right now is the best, just wanted to show that this approach works.

Comment: @Thefourthbird I simplified the code a bit in the original link. `Regex.Matches(line, @"\((?<word>\w+)(?:\|(?<word>\w+))*\)").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Groups["word"].Captures)` is enough.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks! I changed the Select to SelectMany to Flatten the list and then we can use a single foreach right?

Comment: @Thefourthbird Right, `.SelectMany` fetches flattened items. We do not know the exact scenario here, so any will do.